# When I press create account in my app, it creates it without any info

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I've been trying to figure this problem out for a few days and can't seem to find a solution that works.

The problem is: When I try to create an account in my app, it automatically creates an account without entering any information. So basically the user puts no info and the account is still being created.

I'm currently using Firebase

Here is the code for that View:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class createAccountVC: UIViewController {

private let RIDER_SEGUE = "createAccountSegue"

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var createAccountButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    createAccountButton.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 2
    createAccountButton.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
}

private func alertTheUser(title: String, message: String) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
    alert.addAction(ok)
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}


@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {

if emailTextField.text != "" && passwordTextField.text != "" && confirmPasswordTextField.text != "" {

    AuthProvider.Instance.signUp(withEmail: emailTextField.text!, password: passwordTextField.text!, loginHandler: { (message) in
        if message != nil {
            self.alertTheUser(title: "Problem with creating a new user.", message: message!)
        } else {
            GroomrHandler.Instance.rider = self.emailTextField.text!
            self.saveUserInfo(email: self.emailTextField.text!, password: self.passwordTextField.text!)
            self.emailTextField.text = ""
            self.passwordTextField.text = ""
            self.confirmPasswordTextField.text = ""
            //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.RIDER_SEGUE, sender: nil)
            // save password to keychain
        }

    })

} else {
    alertTheUser(title: "Email and password are required.", message: "Please enter email and password in the text fields.")
}

}
func saveUserInfo(email: String, password: String) {

    //save login info in app
    UserDefaults.standard.set(email, forKey: "email")



}
}
```

Thank you in advance! Don't flame me, I'm still learning XD

EDIT: Here is the AuthProvider File:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String?) -> Void

struct LoginErrorCode {
static let INVALID_EMAIL = "Invalid email address, please provide a      real email address."
static let WRONG_PASSWORD = "Wrong password, please enter the correct password."
static let PROBLEM_CONNECTING = "Problem connecting to database, please try later."
static let USER_NOT_FOUND = "User not found, please register."
static let EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE = "Email already in use, please use another email."
static let WEAK_PASSWORD = "Password should be at least 6 characters long."
}

class AuthProvider {
private static let _instance = AuthProvider()

static var Instance: AuthProvider {
    return _instance
}

func login(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            self.handleErrors(err: error! as NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)
        } else {
            loginHandler?(nil)
        }

    })

} // login func

func signUp(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil {
            self.handleErrors(err: error! as NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)
        } else {

            if user?.uid != nil {


                // login the user
                self.login(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler)

            }

        }

    })

} // sign up func

func logOut() -> Bool {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        do {
            try Auth.auth().signOut()
            return true
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

private func handleErrors(err: NSError, loginHandler: LoginHandler?) {

    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code) {

        switch errCode {

        case .wrongPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD)
            break

        case .invalidEmail:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.INVALID_EMAIL)
            break

        case .userNotFound:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND)
            break

        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE)
            break

        case .weakPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WEAK_PASSWORD)
            break

        default:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.PROBLEM_CONNECTING)
            break

        }

    }

}

} // class
```

Comment: What do you mean it creates the account without any info? I think what you want is this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start and this Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password).

Comment: same problem, it still creates an account even though I don't put email, password, confirm password, in the textfields, just directly goes to the other view.

Comment: If there are values in your textfield it creates an account with the credentials ?

Comment: As UiTextfield text property provide an optional string, you should first unwrap that and then check for empty. Otherwise with you current code nil text will pass the if condition.

Comment: I'm going with @Mike on his comment.. what is *AuthProvider.Instance.signUp*? Do you define AuthProvider somewhere? Where is .createUser?

Comment: @Adeel can you upload the screen grab of what you see in Firebase Authentication

Comment: @Jay Yes I have another file that says AuthProvider

Answer (score 0):

I had some experience in registering users, here is my code, you may try it. Hope that it helps.

This in User object:

```
Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error == nil {
            user?.sendEmailVerification(completion: nil)
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("usersProfilePics").child(user!.uid)
            let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profilePic, 0.1)
            storageRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil, completion: { (metadata, err) in
                if err == nil {
                    let path = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    let values = ["name": withName, "email": email, "profilePicLink": path!]
                    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userType).child((user?.uid)!).child("credentials").updateChildValues(values, withCompletionBlock: { (errr, _) in
                        if errr == nil {
                            let userInfo = ["email" : email, "password" : password, "type" : userType]
                            UserDefaults.standard.set(userInfo, forKey: "userInformation")
                            completion(true)
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
        }
        else {
            completion(false)
        }
    })
```

Here I am calling method of User object:

```
User.registerUser(withName: self.registerNameField.text!, email: self.registerEmailField.text!, password: self.registerPasswordField.text!, profilePic: self.profilePicView.image!, forUserType: UserType.psychologist) { [weak weakSelf = self] (status) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            weakSelf?.showLoading(state: false)
            for item in self.inputFields {
                item.text = ""
            }
            if status == true {
                weakSelf?.pushTomainView()
                weakSelf?.profilePicView.image = UIImage.init(named: "profile pic")
            } else {
                for item in (weakSelf?.waringLabels)! {
                    item.isHidden = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi. What is the difference between AuthProvider.Instance.signUp and Auth.auth().createUser

Answer (score 0):

```
var abcd: String?
if abcd != "" {
    print("hello")
}
```

The above code prints `hello` in the console. Similar issue is happening in your code. condition `abcd != ""` only test for empty, not nil. You should first unwrap all textfield text, then check for `isEmpty`, and create account.

```
@IBAction func signUp(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text,
        let password = passwordTextField.text,
        let confirmPassword = confirmPasswordTextField.text,
        email != "",
        password != "",
        confirmPassword != "" else {
            alertTheUser(title: "Email and password are required.", message: "Please enter email and password in the text fields.")
    }

    AuthProvider.Instance.signUp(withEmail: email, password: password, loginHandler: { (message) in
        if message != nil {
            self.alertTheUser(title: "Problem with creating a new user.", message: message!)
        } else {
            GroomrHandler.Instance.rider = email
            self.saveUserInfo(email: email, password: password)
            self.emailTextField.text = ""
            self.passwordTextField.text = ""
            self.confirmPasswordTextField.text = ""
            //self.performSegue(withIdentifier: self.RIDER_SEGUE, sender: nil)
            // save password to keychain
        }

    })
}
```